# Returning value from ArcGIS Pro custom tool (.py)

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-script-tool, parameters, python-toolbox

How do we return a value from a custom .py tool, so that when I run the tool in another script, it will return a value (such as a number, string, or tuple)?

Notice in the execute class function, I attempt to return a tuple of values (trying both `arcpy.SetParameter` and `return`). However, when I run the tool in a separate script, the return value is `None`.

I use the following code to import the toolbox and run the code:

```py
arcpy.ImportToolbox(pyt_path, "myToolbox")
result = arcpy.myToolbox.HelloWorld()
```

Below is an example .py script for the tool above

```py
import arcpy

class HelloWorld(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
        self.label = "Hello World"
        self.description = ""
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        
        """Define parameter definitions"""
        param1 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="output",
            name="outparam",
            datatype="GPString",
            parameterType="Derived",
            direction="Output")

        return [param1]

    def isLicensed(self):
        """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
        return True

    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
        validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
        has been changed."""
        return

    def updateMessages(self, parameters):
        """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
        parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
        return

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        """The source code of the tool."""      
        arcpy.AddMessage("Hello World!")
        arcpy.SetParameter(0, "Hello world")
        return "Hello world"

    def postExecute(self, parameters):
        """This method takes place after outputs are processed and
        added to the display."""
        return
```

Below is my .pyt file

```py
from HelloWorld import HelloWorld

class Toolbox(object):

    def __init__(self):
        """Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of the .pyt file)."""
        self.label = 'Test TBX'
        self.alias = 'TestTBX'

        # List of Tool classes associated with this toolbox
        self.tools = [HelloWorld]
```

---

Here is a regular arcpy example using their Spatial Analyst toolbox. I would like to get a return value as well with my custom tool.

```py
# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import Basin

# Set environment settings
env.workspace = "C:/Path/To/Data"

# Set local variables
inFlowDirectionRaster = "flowdir"

# Execute FlowDirection
outBasin = Basin(inFlowDirectionRaster)
```

Comment: Read the help file on SetParameter()

Comment: I tried that option and I could not get it to work. I will edit my code to add that example.

Comment: Now I see your example code, I repeat _read_ the help file, you are making up syntax that does not exist. Look at the sample code on the help page.

Comment: I forgot to include the update to the `getParameterInfo` function. Other than that, I am unsure of how to move forward.

Comment: I'm not seeing anywhere in your examples where you run the HelloWorld tool?

Comment: Look at the help file what is in the syntax section, what data type is `index`? what have you put in? Is it an integer? You need to read the help and understand what the input data types are for a function such as SetParameter().

Comment: According to the docs, you can pass by name or by index. I tried both. Neither work.

Comment: @Hornbydd I tried both methods, neither work. If you find a solution, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code worked fine for me returning the text Hello world. My script was:

```py
arcpy.ImportToolbox(r"C:\Temp\ORN\t2.pyt","TestTBX" )
res = arcpy.TestTBX.HelloWorld()
print(res.getOutput(0))
```

The only things I did was to ensure the HelloWorld.py file was in the same folder as the PYT file and removed the text after the return statement in the execute function; you do not need that as you are passing out the text through the SetParameter(), which you are now correctly defining.